# CSS Calc setting a new z-index value based on current z-index value

Tags: css, leaflet, z-index, css-calc

I have a Leaflet map with hundreds of map markers.
Some of these map markers are underneath others, as the map is crowded.

The user would like certain types or criteria of markers to appear on the top of the marker "stack" on the map.

This is easily done with adjusting the Z-index of each marker element.

The marker elements currently have this below CSS, which is loop-generated by Leaflet.js in the construction/population phase:

```
/* Constructed by Leaflet 1.7 */
element {
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 30px;
    transform: translate3d(551px, 252px, 0px);
    z-index: 58;
    outline: currentcolor none medium;
}
```

The value of z-index is a counter of markers, so this marker is number 58, and the *next* marker, (regardless of its position on the map) has `z-index: 59;`, etc.

Here is an example difference, with manually edited z-index;

[image]
*Above; some red pins are hidden behind blue pins. These would need to be promoted to be more visible.*

[image]
*Above; red pins are promoted above other pins via z-index editing, but also retain their stacking with each other (Ascending)*.

However, because the number of markers is variable the value of `z-index` is also variable. I can of course update all of these with javascript, and I'm almost certain that will have to be done, but I was curious if:

## Is there a way with CSS (only) to relatively update the `z-index` value, based on its current value?

For example; to 'promote' this marker could be `z-index: calc(<current_value> + 200);`

However, I can not find a CSS-only way of catching the current value of Z-index; most "calc" current values use 100% but Z-index does not use percentage.

**Why can't we just set it to some high number?**
Using some arbitary high catch-all value will not give an ideal result because, for example, setting the `z-index` to `9999` means all the selected marker elements will have the same z-index. The markers are output from database data and ordered in a certain way (in this case, by *date*), so the group of markers that are "promoted" should still be *relative to each other*, while being promoted with an added value to their `z-index` above those who are not in the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're wrong in this part of your analysis:

> The value of z-index is a counter of markers, so this marker is number 58, and the next marker, (regardless of its position on the map) has `z-index: 59;`, etc.

Leaflet manages the `zIndex` of the marker icons so that markers further north (up) have a greater `zIndex` than those south (down), [with this bit of code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/838587dff062af1af89c2ae7ca60e451e0e4de26/src/layer/marker/Marker.js#L299), setting a value that is later applied to the CSS property of the icon's `ImageHTMLElement`:

```
this._zIndex = pos.y + this.options.zIndexOffset;
```

But Leaflet markers have a [`zIndexOffset` option](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#marker-zindexoffset) to control the kind of issue you're facing. There's also [a `setZIndexOffset` method](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#marker-setzindexoffset) available in `L.Marker`s to change this value, e.g.:

```
marker1.setZIndexOffset(100);
marker2.setZIndexOffset(0);
```

Assuming that you have markers in a `L.LayerGroup` (or a `L.FeatureGroup` or `L.GeoJSON`), you can leverage [its `invoke` method](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#layergroup-invoke) to call `setZIndexOffset` on all of its markers at the same time, e.g.

```
groupWithRedMarkers.invoke("setZIndexOffset", 100);
groupWithBlueMarkers.invoke("setZIndexOffset", 0);
```

The value of `zIndexOffset` should be at least the height of the marker icons (measured in CSS pixels), since Leaflet uses screen pixel coordinates to calculate the final `zIndex` values. Remember to reset the `zIndexOffset`s to zero when needed.

---

Another approach would be to leverage [map panes](https://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/), assuming that the criteria to display markers on top/bottom doesn't change through time.

The tl;dr version would be:

```
map.createPane('topmarkers');
map.getPane('topmarkers').style.zIndex = 650;
marker = L.Marker(latlng, {pane: 'topmarkers'});
```

---

> Is there a way with CSS (only) to relatively update the z-index value, based on its current value?

No, since Leaflet changes the z-index of markers dynamically as the user pans and zooms the map.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and clarifications. I suspected there was not a way of adjusting the z-index in this way, but thought it was interesting enough to ask. Cheers.

Comment: Using the Leaflet map pane system did exactly what I need, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

One idea could be the use of `translateZ()` to promote all the elements the same way but I see that you already have transform applied. You can probably apply it to another wrapper.

Here is an illustration of the idea:

```js
$('.box i').each(function() {
  var z = $(this).index();
  $(this).css('z-index',z);
});
```

```css
.box{
  padding:20px;
  counter-reset:num;
  transform-style:preserve-3d; /* here */
}
.box i {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  margin:0 -5px;
  border-radius:50%;
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  background:blue;
  border:2px solid green;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:25px;
}
.box i::before {
  content:counter(num);
  counter-increment:num;
}
.box i.red {
  background:red;
  transform:translateZ(1px); /* and here */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
<i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i class="red"></i><i></i><i></i><i class="red"></i><i></i><i class="red"></i><i></i><i></i><i class="red"></i><i></i><i></i><i class="red"></i><i class="red"></i><i class="red"></i><i></i><i></i><i></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Wondering if you can't also use `counter-increment` for this ?

Comment: @TylerH not yet (https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1026) .. counter return a string and actually only allowed inside content ... maybe in the near future.

Comment: That's a nice idea. The Leaflet generated transform sticks at  `0px` for Z axis so definetely possible to transform it for those elements. However a quick test right now the result doesn't work, because I forgot the `preserve-3d`. I Will explore tomorrow.

Comment: @Martin did you add `transform-style:preserve-3d;` on an upper element? it's mandatory

Comment: @TemaniAfif I had only just noticed that oversight and yes, correcting that the Translation does appear to work on the map markers. I will look with fresh eyes tomorrow, but cheers for the fresh approach `:-)`

Comment: Unfortunately this got way to complex as another layer could not be added into the CSS and appending a class to alter the transform obviously doesn't work. Altering the exsiting leaflet CSS with javascript would be a workable workaround but if using JS I'd rather use the intended Leaflet Pane system.